# Azure: Do I need a Azure ML resource to use AutoML in an Azure databricks notebook?

Tags: databricks, azure-machine-learning-service, automl

If I want to use AutoML to train models within a python Databricks notebook, do I need an Azure Machine Learning resource? It seems like this would be an unnecessary resource if Databricks has its own compute

Comment: you mean specific AutoML implementation, like Azure's? Or it's some other, that isn't bound to Azure?

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "resource"? Do you mean an AML workspace? or AML Compute Target? You definitely need a workspace, but not so sure about the AML Compute. My gut tells me that AutoML is built to work on the custom-built managed compute, which is why it might not work on Databricks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, yes AutoML and Databricks ML libraries are completely different things.

Generic Random Forest Regression:

```
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.regression import RandomForestRegressor
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorIndexer
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import RegressionEvaluator

# Load and parse the data file, converting it to a DataFrame.
data = spark.read.format("libsvm").load("data/mllib/sample_libsvm_data.txt")

# Automatically identify categorical features, and index them.
# Set maxCategories so features with > 4 distinct values are treated as continuous.
featureIndexer =\
    VectorIndexer(inputCol="features", outputCol="indexedFeatures", maxCategories=4).fit(data)

# Split the data into training and test sets (30% held out for testing)
(trainingData, testData) = data.randomSplit([0.7, 0.3])

# Train a RandomForest model.
rf = RandomForestRegressor(featuresCol="indexedFeatures")

# Chain indexer and forest in a Pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[featureIndexer, rf])

# Train model.  This also runs the indexer.
model = pipeline.fit(trainingData)

# Make predictions.
predictions = model.transform(testData)

# Select example rows to display.
predictions.select("prediction", "label", "features").show(5)

# Select (prediction, true label) and compute test error
evaluator = RegressionEvaluator(
    labelCol="label", predictionCol="prediction", metricName="rmse")
rmse = evaluator.evaluate(predictions)
print("Root Mean Squared Error (RMSE) on test data = %g" % rmse)

rfModel = model.stages[1]
print(rfModel)  # summary only
```

Generic Random Forest Classification:

```
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.classification import RandomForestClassifier
from pyspark.ml.feature import IndexToString, StringIndexer, VectorIndexer
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import MulticlassClassificationEvaluator

# Load and parse the data file, converting it to a DataFrame.
data = spark.read.format("libsvm").load("data/mllib/sample_libsvm_data.txt")

# Index labels, adding metadata to the label column.
# Fit on whole dataset to include all labels in index.
labelIndexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="label", outputCol="indexedLabel").fit(data)

# Automatically identify categorical features, and index them.
# Set maxCategories so features with > 4 distinct values are treated as continuous.
featureIndexer =\
    VectorIndexer(inputCol="features", outputCol="indexedFeatures", maxCategories=4).fit(data)

# Split the data into training and test sets (30% held out for testing)
(trainingData, testData) = data.randomSplit([0.7, 0.3])

# Train a RandomForest model.
rf = RandomForestClassifier(labelCol="indexedLabel", featuresCol="indexedFeatures", numTrees=10)

# Convert indexed labels back to original labels.
labelConverter = IndexToString(inputCol="prediction", outputCol="predictedLabel",
                               labels=labelIndexer.labels)

# Chain indexers and forest in a Pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[labelIndexer, featureIndexer, rf, labelConverter])

# Train model.  This also runs the indexers.
model = pipeline.fit(trainingData)

# Make predictions.
predictions = model.transform(testData)

# Select example rows to display.
predictions.select("predictedLabel", "label", "features").show(5)

# Select (prediction, true label) and compute test error
evaluator = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(
    labelCol="indexedLabel", predictionCol="prediction", metricName="accuracy")
accuracy = evaluator.evaluate(predictions)
print("Test Error = %g" % (1.0 - accuracy))

rfModel = model.stages[2]
print(rfModel)  # summary only
```

Please check out the resource below for more info.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html